# How can I solve my problems with the installation of the text2vec package?

Tags: r, installation, text2vec

I'm trying to install the R package text2vec, I get the following error.
It says it cannot open a certain shared object file.

```
> install.packages("text2vec")
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/var/R/library/rsparse/libs/rsparse.so':
  float.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘text2vec’
* removing ‘/var/R/library/text2vec’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘text2vec’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is my session info:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.3.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] readr_1.4.0        usethis_2.0.1      purrr_0.3.4        rebus_0.1-3        testthat_3.0.3     stringi_1.6.2      scales_1.1.1      
 [8] tictoc_1.0.1       ggplot2_3.3.3      topicmodels_0.2-12 udpipe_0.8.6       tidytext_0.3.1     tidyr_1.1.3        stringr_1.4.0     
[15] dplyr_1.0.5        odbc_1.3.2        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6            lubridate_1.7.10      lattice_0.20-41       assertthat_0.2.1      utf8_1.2.1            slam_0.1-48          
 [7] plyr_1.8.6            cellranger_1.1.0      R6_2.5.0              stats4_4.0.3          quanteda_3.1.0        pillar_1.5.1         
[13] cld3_1.4.1            rlang_0.4.10          readxl_1.3.1          rstudioapi_0.13       data.table_1.14.0     blob_1.2.1           
[19] Matrix_1.2-18         rebus.base_0.0-3      config_0.3.1          bit_4.0.4             munsell_0.5.0         compiler_4.0.3       
[25] janeaustenr_0.1.5     xfun_0.24             pkgconfig_2.0.3       tidyselect_1.1.0      tibble_3.1.0          rebus.numbers_0.0-1  
[31] fansi_0.4.2           crayon_1.4.1          dbplyr_2.1.1          withr_2.4.1           SnowballC_0.7.0       grid_4.0.3           
[37] gtable_0.3.0          lifecycle_1.0.0       DBI_1.1.1             magrittr_2.0.1        tokenizers_0.2.1      RcppParallel_5.1.4   
[43] cli_2.4.0             reshape2_1.4.4        fs_1.5.0              NLP_0.2-1             xml2_1.3.2            stopwords_2.2        
[49] ellipsis_0.3.1        generics_0.1.0        vctrs_0.3.7           fastmatch_1.1-3       wordcloud_2.6         RColorBrewer_1.1-2   
[55] tools_4.0.3           bit64_4.0.5           glue_1.4.2            rebus.unicode_0.0-2   hms_1.0.0             rebus.datetimes_0.0-1
[61] parallel_4.0.3        yaml_2.2.1            tm_0.7-8              colorspace_2.0-0      knitr_1.33            modeltools_0.2-23
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Since the actual issue seems to be the rsparse package, try installing it first. You also might want to install without so many packages being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the `float` package and the way R installs dependencies when not using "staged installs". What you can do here is to first reinstall the `float` package, and once it is reinstalled, reinstall the `rsparse` package. If that still doesn't work - and this is specific to `float` which uses dynamic linking - perhaps try installing `float` manually, changing the configuration to ensure that it uses your currently installed BLAS library (here openblas).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I have tried reinstalling the packages but unfortunately this does not help. Could you tell me how I can install float manually and change the configuration?

Comment: @NinavanBruggen you'd have to edit the configure script: https://github.com/wrathematics/float/blob/66f05784c7c6b81799f57daae9c4413cd9dc18f9/configure.ac#L94 - are you getting any error message from `float`? Strage that it fails like that. Also, are you installing grom CRAN or from some mirror like MRAN? Perhaps you could also check in `rsparse`'s configure script if the arguments it determines for linking to `float` are correct or not: https://github.com/rexyai/rsparse/blob/66df48a72d1f6105f41f0d54088b5538d0217418/configure.ac#L15

Comment: Thank you! It's my work environment. I use the package manager and I work on Rstudio Server Pro (which is now called the workbench I think). Earlier on the fact that we use package manager and RHEL7 was the cause of package problems. I also don't have an internet connection on that server because of security reasons.

Comment: @NinavanBruggen what do you get from `library(float)`? Also, did it show any error message when installing?

Comment: No error messages while installing. The problem starts when I load rsparse: 
> library(rsparse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rsparse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/var/R/library/rsparse/libs/rsparse.so':
  float.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rsparse’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Comment: @NinavanBruggen that means you haven't reinstalled `rsparse`, and it also looks like you have parallel R installs and you're mixing packages between them. Perhaps the installation failed and it kept an older version?

Answer (score 0):

on my case with text2vec ubuntu 22.04 R 4.3.1 the loading problems was fixed by installing libopenblas-dev at the os